# Using AwId.dll in delphi XE6

Tags: c#, delphi, dll, dllimport, delphi-xe6

I have never done a call to a C# dll before and as I search the internet I got more confused.

As I understand I have to create the procedure/functions of the dll.

I have the example C# code an there it is declared like this.

```cs
private delegate void OpCompletedDelegate(AwidMpr.OperationCompleteEventArgs e);
private delegate void TagReadResponseDelegate(AwidMpr.TagReadEventArgs e);
private delegate void DeviceErrorDelegate(AwidMpr.ErrorEventArgs e);
```

I tried this in interface:

```pascal
procedure OperationCompleteEventArgs (); stdcall;
```

But I think I'm missing some parameters for the e that shows in the C#

I tried to add this in the implementation, but it is not working I get an error saying the function needs result type..

```pascal
const 
  AwidMpr= 'AwidMpr.dll';
  procedure OperationCompleteEventArgs; external AwidMpr name 'OperationCompleteEventArgs';
```

I understand that there need to be a result from any function, but in the C# declaration I just see a e

Here is the demo program in C# that comes with the dll.

Hope someone can get me in the right direction, Thanks.

```cs
namespace AWIDMPRSimpleReadDemo
begin
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    begin
        private delegate void OpCompletedDelegate(AwidMpr.OperationCompleteEventArgs e);
        private delegate void TagReadResponseDelegate(AwidMpr.TagReadEventArgs e);
        private delegate void DeviceErrorDelegate(AwidMpr.ErrorEventArgs e);

        #region Variables
        private const string DATA_TABLE_NAME := 'TagInventory';
        private Integer _activeTagInventorySize;
        private DataTable _tagInventoryTable := null;
        private Integer _defaultTagInventorySize := 50;
        private const string COL_TAG_ID := 'EPC Number/Tag ID/Data';
        private const string COL_CNT := 'Reads';
        private const string COL_FIRST := 'First';
        private const string COL_LAST := 'Last';

        private byte cmd := 0x00;
        private string cmdStr := 'Single Tag ID';
        private AwidMpr.MprDevice device := null;
        private ArrayList tagsRead := null;
        private string origTitle := null;

        private Boolean isNetwork := true;
        #endregion

        private void InitializeTagInventoryTable()
        begin
            Integer sz := Properties.Settings.Default.TagInventorySize;
            if (sz < := 0) then
                _activeTagInventorySize := _defaultTagInventorySize
            else _activeTagInventorySize := sz;
            this._tagInventoryTable := new DataTable(DATA_TABLE_NAME);

            DataColumn col := new DataColumn(COL_TAG_ID, Type.GetType('System.String'));
            this._tagInventoryTable.Columns.Add(col);

            col := new DataColumn(COL_CNT, Type.GetType('System.String'));
            this._tagInventoryTable.Columns.Add(col);

            col := new DataColumn(COL_FIRST, Type.GetType('System.String'));
            this._tagInventoryTable.Columns.Add(col);

            col := new DataColumn(COL_LAST, Type.GetType('System.String'));
            this._tagInventoryTable.Columns.Add(col);
        end;
        private DataRow RowInTable(DataTable dt, DataRow drCheck, string criteriaColumn)
        begin
            DataRow drMatch := null;
            foreach (DataRow drExisting in dt.Rows)
            begin
                if (drExisting[criteriaColumn].ToString() = drCheck[criteriaColumn].ToString()) then
                begin
                    drMatch := drExisting;
                    break;
                end;
            end;

            (* C2PAS: Exit *) Result := drMatch;
        end;
        public Form1()
        begin
            InitializeComponent();
#if UseLogo
else
            this.pictureBox1.Visible := false;
#endif
            var app := Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() then .GetName();
            this.Text := ' ' + app.Name + ' V' + app.Version;
#if DEBUG
else
            this.Text + := ' (AwidMpr: ' + AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName('AwidMpr.dll') then .Version + ')';
#endif
            this.origTitle := this.Text;
            this.InitializeTagInventoryTable();
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource := this._tagInventoryTable;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width := 320;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width := 130;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width := 200;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width := 200;
        end;

        private void toolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        begin
            string name := ((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Name;
            ToolStripMenuItem[] mbrs := begin this.toolStripMenuItem2, this.toolStripMenuItem3,
                this.toolStripMenuItem4 end; ;
            foreach (ToolStripMenuItem mtm in mbrs)
            begin
                if (name.Equals(mtm.Name)) then continue;
                mtm.Checked := false;
            end;
            this.cmdStr := ((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Text;
            string val := this.cmdStr.ToLower();
            if (val.Contains('single tag id')) then this.cmd := 0x00
            else if (val.Contains('meter')) then this.cmd := 0x11
            else if (val.Contains('portal')) then this.cmd := 0x1E;
        end;
        private void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        begin
            Button btn := (Button)sender;
            if ( not this.device.Connected) then
            begin
                MessageBox.Show('Device not connected! Get out.', btnClear.Text,
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                (* C2PAS: Exit *) Result :=;
            end;
            if (btn.Text.Equals('Start')) then
            begin
                if (this.tagsRead <> null) then this.tagsRead.Clear();
                this._tagInventoryTable.Clear();
                try
                begin
                    case (this.cmd) of
                    begin
                        0x00:
                            this.device.StartEpcC1G2ReadSingleTagId();
                            break;
                        0x11:
                            this.device.StartEpcC1G2SingleTagMeter();
                            break;
                        0x1E:
                            this.device.StartEpcC1G2PortalIds(0, 0);
                            break;
                        else
                            (* C2PAS: Exit *) Result :=;
                    end;
                end;
                except (Exception ex)
                begin
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, 'Executing ''' + this.cmdStr + '''',
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    (* C2PAS: Exit *) Result :=;
                end;
                btn.Text := 'Stop';
                this.btnClear.Enabled := this.panel1.Enabled := this.menuStrip1.Enabled := false;
            end
            else
            begin
                try
                begin
                    this.doStop();
                end;
                except (Exception ex)
                begin
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, 'Stop', MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    (* C2PAS: Exit *) Result :=;
                end;
                btn.Text := 'Start';
                this.btnClear.Enabled := this.panel1.Enabled := this.menuStrip1.Enabled := true;
            end;
        end;
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        begin
            this._tagInventoryTable.Clear();
        end;
        private void doConnect()
        begin
            if (this.device <> null and this.device.Connected) then
            begin
                try
                begin
                    this.device.Disconnect();
                end;
                except (Exception e)
                begin
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, 'Close old connection', MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    (* C2PAS: Exit *) Result :=;
                end;
                this.device := null;
            end;
            string s := null;
            try
            begin
                if (this.isNetwork) then
                begin
                    this.device := new AwidMpr.MprDevice(new AwidMpr.TcpConnectionSettings(
                        this.tbxIP.Text.Trim(), 4000));
                    s := this.device.Connect(true);
                end
                else
                begin
                    this.device := new AwidMpr.MprDevice(new AwidMpr.SerialConnectionSettings(
                        this.cbxComPort.Text, Convert.ToInt32(this.cbxSpeed.Text)));
                    this.device.Connect();
                end;
            end;
            except (Exception e)
            begin
                s := 'Make sure ' + (this.isNetwork ? 'IP' : 'COM Port/Speed combo') + ' entry is valid.';
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message + Environment.NewLine + s, 'Connect',
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                this.tbxIP.Focus();
                (* C2PAS: Exit *) Result :=;
            end;
            try
            begin
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20);
                s := this.device.GetFirmwareVersion();
            end;
            except (Exception e)
            begin
                MessageBox.Show('Initial FWV Retrieval failed: ' + e.Message, 'Connect',
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            end;
            this.Text + := ' ' + s;
            s := null;
            this.device.TagRead + := new EventHandler<AwidMpr.TagReadEventArgs>(device_TagRead);
            this.device.Error + := new EventHandler<AwidMpr.ErrorEventArgs>(device_Error);
            this.device.OperationCompleted + :=
                new EventHandler<AwidMpr.OperationCompleteEventArgs>(device_OperationCompleted);
            this.panel2.Enabled := this.menuStrip1.Enabled := true;
            this.button1.Text := 'Disconnect';
            this.panel3.Enabled := false;
        end;
        public void logUpdate(string s)
        begin
            if (this.txtLog.Text.Length + s.Length > this.txtLog.MaxLength) then
            begin
                this.txtLog.Text := '';
            end;
            this.txtLog.Text + := (this.txtLog.Text.Length > 0 ? Environment.NewLine : '') +
                DateTime.Now.ToString() + ' ' + s;
        end;
        private void device_OperationCompleted(object sender, AwidMpr.OperationCompleteEventArgs e)
        begin
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            this.logUpdate('Cmd: ' + e.Command.ToString() + ', Protocol: ' + e.CommandType.ToString() +
                ', Status: ' + e.Status.ToString());
        end;
        private void device_Error(object sender, AwidMpr.ErrorEventArgs e)
        begin
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            this.logUpdate('Device Error: ' + e.Exception.ToString());
        end;
        private void device_TagRead(object sender, AwidMpr.TagReadEventArgs e)
        begin
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            try
            begin
                Control ctrl := this.dataGridView1;
                if (ctrl.InvokeRequired) then
                begin
                    //IAsyncResult result = // needed if will use EndInvoke which is not req'd on controls
                    ctrl.BeginInvoke(new TagReadResponseDelegate(this.displayTag),
                    new object[] begin e end; );
                end
                else this.displayTag(e);
            end;
            except (Exception ex)
            begin
                // what do we do here????
                string errMsg := '';
                errMsg + := ex.Message;
            end;
        end;
        private void doDisconnect()
        begin
            if (this.device <> null) then
            begin
                try
                begin
                    if (this.device.Connected) then this.device.Disconnect();
                end;
                except (Exception e)
                begin
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, 'Disonnect', MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                end;
                this.device := null;
            end;
            this._tagInventoryTable.Clear();
            this.txtLog.Text := '';
            this.panel2.Enabled := this.menuStrip1.Enabled := false;
            this.button1.Text := 'Connect';
            this.Text := this.origTitle;
            this.panel3.Enabled := true;
        end;
        private void ConnectClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        begin
            if (((Button)sender).Text.Equals('Connect')) then
                this.doConnect()
            else this.doDisconnect();
        end;
        private string getTimeStamp()
        begin
            DateTime dt := DateTime.Now;
            string timeVal := String.Format('{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}:{3:D3}' +
                ' {4:D2}/{5:d2}/{6:d4}',
                dt.Hour, dt.Minute, dt.Second, dt.Millisecond,
                dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Year);
            (* C2PAS: Exit *) Result := timeVal;
        end;
        private void displayTag(AwidMpr.TagReadEventArgs args)
        begin
            if (args.TagId = null or args.TagId.Length < := 1) then (* C2PAS: Exit *) Result :=;
            if (this.tagsRead = null) then this.tagsRead := new ArrayList(1);
            string timestamp := '';
            try
            begin
                if (this._tagInventoryTable <> null and this._tagInventoryTable.Columns.Count > 0) then
                begin
                    AwidMpr.TagReadEventArgs e := args;
                    DataRow dr := this._tagInventoryTable.NewRow();
                    string tagID := (e.TagId = null or e.TagId.Length < := 0 ?
                        'null' : AwidMpr.Utility.ByteArrayToHexString(e.TagId));
                    if ( not this.tagsRead.Contains(tagID)) then
                    begin
                        this.tagsRead.Add(tagID);
                    end;

                    dr[COL_TAG_ID] := tagID;
                    timestamp := this.getTimeStamp();
                    dr[COL_LAST] := timestamp;
                    Integer readCount := e.TagReadCount;

                    lock (this._tagInventoryTable)
                    begin
                        if (this._tagInventoryTable.Rows.Count = this._activeTagInventorySize) then
                        begin
                            this._tagInventoryTable.Rows.RemoveAt(this._tagInventoryTable.Rows.Count - 1);
                        end;

                        DataRow existingTag := //(e.Command == 0x11 ? null :
                            this.RowInTable(this._tagInventoryTable, dr, COL_TAG_ID)
                            //)
                        ;

                        if (existingTag = null) then
                        begin
                            dr[COL_FIRST] := timestamp;
                            dr[COL_CNT] := readCount;
                            this._tagInventoryTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
                        end
                        else
                        begin
                            readCount + := Convert.ToInt16(existingTag[COL_CNT]);
                            existingTag[COL_CNT] := readCount;
                            existingTag[COL_LAST] := timestamp;
                        end;
                    end;
                end;
            end;
            except (Exception e)
            begin
                throw e;
            end;
        end;
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        begin
            this.doDisconnect();
        end;
        private void doStop()
        begin
            try
            begin
                this.device.Stop();
            end;
            except (Exception e)
            begin
                throw e;
            end;
        end;
        private void StopClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        begin
            try
            begin
                this.doStop();
            end;
            except (Exception ex)
            begin
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, 'Stop', MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            end;
        end;
        private void CommunicationModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        begin
            RadioButton rb := (RadioButton)sender;
            if (rb.Checked) then
            begin
                if (rb.Text.Contains('Serial')) then
                begin
                    this.isNetwork := false;
                end
                else
                begin
                    this.isNetwork := true;
                end;
                this.gbxSerial.Visible := not this.isNetwork;
                this.gbxIP.Visible := this.isNetwork;
            end;
        end;
        private void ComPortDropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        begin
            ComboBox cbCom := (ComboBox)sender;
            string[] strCom := System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            cbCom.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string s in strCom)
            begin
                cbCom.Items.Add(s);
            end;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think the C# assembly exports unmanaged functions that Delphi can consume. You clearly are a little shaky on delphi syntax. You need to be solid on that to contemplate a project like this.

Comment: Regardless of how calling the assembly from Delphi might be done, your function declarations are missing the result type

Comment: `stdcall` is a calling convention, not a data type.  But your declaration is trying to use it as a data type, which is why you are getting an "undeclared identifier" error.

Comment: *"I understand that there need to be a result from any function, but in the C# declaration I just see a e"*. E is the name of the parameter. In C# and .NET event handlers, "multiple" parameters are often passed in the form of one single object (e.g. of type XxYyZzEventArgs) that contains the data one would usually pass as separate parameters. A return type of **void** means nothing is returned (like a procedure in Pascal).

Comment: What would I add as a parameter in the: procedure OperationCompleteEventArgs (); stdcall;

Comment: I know how to program in Delphi, but I know nothing about C#. I was hopping some one knew both and could help me get the dll to work in Delphi. Thanks anyway.